# Is chern classes of holomorphic vector bundles enough to generate Hodge cycles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, vector-bundles, chern-classes

Let $X$ ba a smooth projective variety of dimension $n$. Hodge Conjecture states that every Hodge cycle in $Hdg^k(X,\mathbb{Q})$ comes from a Chern class of codimension $k$ in  $CH^k(X,\mathbb{Q})$. Now the $k$-th Chern class of holomorphic vector bundles generates a subgroup $CH^k_{vec}(X,\mathbb{Q})$. Is it possible that 
 every Hodge cycle in $Hdg^k(X,\mathbb{Q})$ comes from $CH^k_{vec}(X,\mathbb{Q})$? Is there any counterexamples or results?

Comment: Aren't Chern classes of holomorphic vector bundles the same as cycle classes (rationally)? To go from cycles to vector bundles, you can take a finite locally free resolution of the ideal sheaf.

Comment: @WillSawin Thanks! In the Noetherian casse the ideal sheaf of  a closed subvariety is coherent and hence have a finite locally free resolution of coherent sheaves, and then the result follows.